# Use Parsec to parse several different kinds of fields

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have a little parsec parser that can parse tab separated values (TSV) into strings. I want to switch to check for numbers and boolean values (listed as "Y" or "N") in the source file.

Here's the old TSV version (returns `[[String]]`)

```
tsvFile = endBy line newline
line = sepBy cell tab
cell = many (noneOf "\t\n")
```

I would like to change it to support these types:

```
data Cell = CellString String
          | CellNumber Int
          | CellBool Bool          
          deriving (Show)
```

Here are the functions I've defined for number and bool. Are these incorrect?

```
cellBool = do
    b <- oneOf "YN"
    return $ CellBool (b == 'Y')

cellNumber = do
    d <- many digit
    return $ CellNumber (read d)

cellString = do
    s <- many (noneOf "\t\n")
    return $ CellString s
```

And here's what I thought I needed to do to get it to work:

```
cell = cellBool <|> cellNumber <|> cellString
```

But it doesn't work. Running cellNumber before cellString returns `Right []`. If I put `cellString` first in the list, it parses the whole file as strings.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic. Like, only the `cellString` method is dealing with the tab separator I think, but I'm really new to parsec and confused. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Note: I'd like to only parse as a number if the entire cell (up to the next tab) consists of digits, not just if it begins with digits.

Comment: I was going to add this earlier but forgot to: the way I debugged your parsing functions was to give them the signature `ParsecT String u IO Cell`, then insert lines like `liftIO $ putStrLn "Trying cellBool"` and `liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Read text: " ++ show b` around each extraction of text. This is what clued me in to the problem of `many` vs `many1` in `cellNumber` since I could see it never got passed `cellNumber`. Remember that `ParsecT` is a monad transformer meaning that you can always stack other monads with it. Only problem is that you have to use `runParsecT` instead of `parseTest`.

Comment: instead of `cellBool = do {b <- oneOf "YN"; return $ CellBool (b == 'Y')}` you could write `cellBool = fmap (CellBool. (== 'Y')) $ oneOf "YN"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by simply changing the definition of `cellNumber`:

```
cellNumber = do
    d <- many1 digit
    return $ CellNumber (read d)
```

The problem was that `cellNumber` was reading an empty string due to the use of `many`.  Using `many1` means that parser fails, allowing `cellString` to execute.

However, at this point your parser would fail on an input like `"123a\n"`, so you'll need to figure out the backtracking to get that working.

---

Using the definition

```
cellNumber = do
    d <- many1 digit
    lookAhead $ oneOf "\t\n"
    return $ CellNumber (read d)
```

probably isn't ideal.  Instead, I would consider something like

```
cellNumber = do
    d <- many1 digit
    notFollowedBy cellString
    return $ CellNumber (read d)
```

Then change your `cell` function to be

```
cell = try cellBool <|> try cellNumber <|> cellString
```

Comment: Yay thanks! and you're right, I'm now failing on "2b01dcc3" 5 lines down. Can you point me in the right direction for backtracking? Some creative use of `try` or `lookAhead`?

Comment: I edited your example to show lookAhead, but it feels weird to me. Is there a better way to express this? @bheklilr

Comment: @SeanClarkHess I've rolled back your edits in favor of using `notFollowedBy`, although it appears we were editing at the same time and your parser for the end of a cell would probably work too.

Comment: does yours have any performance difference or is it just more clear?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess You might want to consider adding the `notFollowedBy cellString` line in `cellBool` as well, since currently it has the same problem on input like `"Y1\n"`.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess No idea what the performance differences are, it's just my guess that a combinator called `notFollowedBy` would be the correct choice instead of performing a manual `lookAhead`.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess I'm also not going to pretend to be an expert in Parsec, this just looked to be a good solution to this problem.  There may be better solutions out there, maybe someone can add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably run your parser along the lines of

```
parse (tsvFile <* eof) nm s
```

Otherwise, Parsec will find the longest prefix of the file that matches and discard every line after the first parse error.

Second, is it possible that some of your text fields begin with the characters "Y" or "N" or with a digit?  Parsec would only try `cellBool` or `cellNumber` for those fields and the whole parse would fail when they don't match.  You probably want to wrap those two alternatives in `try` to tell Parsec to go on to the next matches if they fail some time after the first character of the field:

```
cell = try cellBool <|> try cellNumber <|> cellString
    -- Don't need try on cellString as it's the last alternative
```

Comment: Could you show me how to wrap my cellNumber in try correctly? Thanks!

Comment: @SeanClarkHess I edited the answer, but `try` is just a function, so it has higher precedence than `<|>`.

Comment: adding `(tsvFile <* eof)` makes it error on the very first character (The first field is `"Crs Prefix Num"`). It still succeeds with only `cell = cellString`, but still fails with a parse error on line 1 column 1 if I include `try`.  Currently `cell = try cellNumber <|> cellString`

Comment: Here's the error: `Left "(unknown)" (line 1, column 1): unexpected 'C'
expecting digit, tab, lf new-line or end of input`

Comment: So it's definitely failing at a more basic level. It's not getting to my `cellString` function even on the first cell, which is `"Crs Prefix Num"`

Comment: Thanks so much for telling me about the the parse line!